# Looking for integers in dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some txt file which contains combination of lists and dictionaries:

```
{"e":[[{"e":86,"c":23,"a":
{"a":[120,169,"green","red","orange"],"b":"red"},"g":"yellow","b":
["yellow"],"d":"red","f":-19},{"e":-47,"a":[2],"d":{"a":"violet"}}
```

I want to find all numbers in this file and get their summary.

I was thinking about maybe iterating over elements by using a for loop and looking for int but it won't work because "for" see elements as all dictionaries or list in this first dictionary and don't go into deeper into dictionaries and lists. I don't want finished program but maybe some clues how I should try to solve this problem.

Comment: can you tell what this summary would look like for your example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regex to look for all numbers and it will be stored in a list then you can carry on:

```
# read text from file
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

import re
match = re.findall(r'-?\d+', text)
print(match)
```

output:

```
['86', '23', '120', '169', '-19', '-47', '2']
```

explaining regex pattern '-?\d+':

'-?' the text may have a sign or not

'\d+' the text contains any amount of adjacent numbers

**Edit**:

as mentioned in comments by @arjoonn, the above pattern might catch numbers within the text, so to avoid that we can add a conditions to our regex pattern, as per below example:

```
import re
text = '2tex809t12 23 [4] -2'
match = re.findall(r'(?<!\w)-?\d+(?!\w)', text)
print(match)
```

output:

```
['23', '4', '-2']
```

explanation:
`'(?!\w)'` called negative lookahead which means the matched text shouldn't contains any characters after our numbers,

and `'(?<!\w)'` is the same as the above but it serves as negative lookbehind i.e. before

Comment: Thanks i didn't knew that read() can sort that mess, I was thinking that its only working for single dictionary or list

Comment: read() will get all file content as a string only, it doesn't identify the contents

Comment: if you need to import this data as a dictionary directly from a file look at json module in python https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: this will fail and wrongly extract a number if it's present as part of a string.

Comment: @arjoonn yes it will fail in this case, but it depend on your data  how it looks like, and you can add more conditions to avoid that , i will add a new pattern in my answer to avoid this